# How does Blender decide in which window it shows the render

Tags: rendering, interface

This has puzzled me for years: How does Blender decide the window where it will display the rendered image when I hit F12 to render?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default it picks the largest area, unless an image editor already exists.

You can alter this behavior by setting the *Display* option in the render settings:

[image]

- *Keep UI*

  Does not change the UI. The render will not be automatically shown.
- *New Window*

  Opens a separate window containing only an image editor  showing the render.
- *Image Editor* (default)

  Renders into an image editor. Turns the largest area into an image editor if one doesn't exist.
- *Full Screen*

  Replaces the UI with a full screen image editor showing the render.

Comment: To be clear for future users redirected from the linked question (how to select the view for the render result): This is not possible to select the target view, the largest one will always be selected and it can be anything (e.g. the dope sheet view -- IMO there is room for improvement here...) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @mins If you want more control over which area is used for displaying the render, one way is to use *Keep UI* and press F11 over the area you want to turn into an image editor/render display area.

Comment: One weird quirk of this is that even if you have the UV/image editor open, the render will only appear there if no image or a previous render is shown in there. However, if you are displaying some other image, such as a texture for uv mapping, it will render to another panel. However, you can get back to the previous view by pressing Esc or F11.

Answer (score 7):

In `2.8` I found this in the top menu `Render/Display Mode`

[image]

Comment: From Blender 2.81, this was moved to User Preferences → Interface → Editors → Temporary Windows.