# How to add windows in a workspace which has no handles?

Tags: interface

I am using Blender 2.75a, and usually use the handles very often to create a  workspace that is relevant to the models I am creating.

[image]

However, I have recently downloaded models that were placed for free on the internet, and I was surprised to see that when opening some models, the windows of Blender (still the same 2.75a version) didn't have handles, which was making it hard to work.

[image]

Were they disabled by the person who made these models, or did these handles appear later? In any case, is there a toggle that turns them on/off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a maximized area.... try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑ Up</kbd>

Comment: ctrl + down made the windows move (OS X feature called control center I think) but shift + space worked. Any idea why when I click render, instead of doing the render in one of the existing workspaces, it does it in a new "maximized area"? Is this a setting? (feel free to add to your good answer)

Comment: @fabriced unless your questions are directly related, please ask new (different) questions on a new post.

Comment: @fabriced: read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33558/how-does-blender-decide-in-which-window-it-shows-the-render

Answer (score 2):

When downloading and opening projects from other people you can force blender to use your default layout and ignore the one the file was saved with.

Use File-> Open (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) to open the file, but make sure to **disable** the **Load UI** option:

[image]

The blend file will then open with the interface you are familiar with...