# How to choose which viewport to render in?

Tags: rendering, interface

I've split the node editor into two viewports and change the second viewport to 3D view. Is there a way to choose which viewport blender will render in? Blender seems to choose randomly.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33558/how-does-blender-decide-in-which-window-it-shows-the-render

Comment: Quite sure Blender uses the larger view.