# How to set up the interface

Tags: rendering, interface, 3d-view

[image]How can I set up my interface with the image editor on the left and viewport on the right in order to be able to see my image immediately in my viewport when I hit render?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33558/how-does-blender-decide-in-which-window-it-shows-the-render.

Comment: Are you asking how to set blender up like you have in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this in Blender. The first and maybe easiest is to click (at the top bar of the program) the little icon with two left cubes, and a tall right one. This will open a bar with different window layouts. Click the one that says "UV Editing." This will give a layout similar to what you want.

Your other option is to manually customize the layout to better fit your preference. To do what you want, look at the top right of the 3D Viewport window for three small lines. Click and hold down that button, and drag to the left. Now, you'll have two windows where the viewport used to be. In the left one (in the bottom left of the window), click the little icon showing a 3D cube. In the window that pops up, select "UV/Image Editor."

Now when you render, the render should show in the UV window instead of the viewport!

[image]

Comment: The rendered result will be shown in the UV/Image editor window regardless, it won't be in 3d viewport unless using viewport render (which is just another thing).

Comment: I think Karoste means the UV image editor based on the picture he has. Otherwise, there is no need to do anything - all he has to do is press F12 and by default the render will be in the Viewport.

Comment: In step one of the image shouldn't it say **Left Here** for left click?

Comment: Oops, my mistake! I meant, look right here for the button to split windows. But yeah, you do want to pull it left at that point.