# Where is the render display mode setting in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, interface, versions

In 2.7x and earlier we have [a setting which controls where the rendered image is displayed when <kbd>F12</kbd> was pressed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33558/599).

The setting can still be set via the python api (`bpy.context.scene.render.display_mode`), but I can't seem to find it in the gui anywhere. Is it still there? If so, where is it?

Comment: I think it has been removed (at least temporarily), the idea is to avoid "temporary layouts" I believe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 2.81 these settings have been moved to *User Preferences > Interface > Editors > Temporary Windows*:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for[image]

Good LUck